# How to pass an item from knockout foreach to partial view as data-bind?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a table with the list `myListB()` of objects, which are displayed by `knockout foreach` making as many rows as `myListB().Count`.

```
<!--ko with: myProperty-->
    <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column 1</th>
                            <th>Column 2</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- ko foreach: myListB()-->
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: Property1"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: Property2"></td>
                            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/MyView.cshtml", this)
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

Data Model:

```
    class viewmodel{
    public myProperty:Foo;
    
    }
    class Foo{
public myListB: KnockoutObservableArray<Model1> = ko.observableArray([])
public myPropertyA:string;
    }
 class Model1{
    public Property1:any;
    public Property2:any;
    }
```

Is there a way to pass an item from foreach to partial view MyView.cshtml (it would be an object of type `Model1`), so I could use it for `data-bind` in partial view and access there value of `Property1` of each item of array `myListB()`? As it's written in code,  `myProperty` is passed by `ko with`, so in partial view I can access either whole `myListB()` or `myPropertyA`. Wrapping partial view with `ko with: $data` doesn't help, I still can access only `myPropertyA` and the whole `myListB()`.
I can't get rid of foreach and partial view here, it should remain as it is now, the question is about the possibility of data binding an array item from foreach to partial view

MyView.cshtml:

```
<div class="modal"
      role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog"
         role="document">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">MyTitle</h4>
            </div>
            <!--ko if: $data!=null -->
            <div class="modal-body ">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Property1"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that knockoutjs runs in the client browser where as `@await Html.PartialAsync` runs on the server. By the time knockoutjs is processing the contents of `myListB`, the server has already processed and rendered the partial view as html as is part of the table row.

so what I think you are seeing on the client side is something like the following in the browser.

```js
    function viewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.myProperty = ko.observable(new Foo());

    }

    function Foo() {
      var self = this;
      self.myListB = ko.observableArray([new Model1(), new Model1()]);
      self.myPropertyA = '';
    }

    function Model1() {
      var self = this;
      self.Property1 = "test 1";
      self.Property2 = "test 2";
    }

    var vm = new viewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!--ko with: myProperty-->
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: myListB-->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Property1"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Property2"></td>

        <div class="modal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content ">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">MyTitle</h4>
              </div>
              <!--ko if: $data!=null -->
              <div class="modal-body ">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Property1"></span>
              </div>
              <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)" />
```

Part of the problem that I can see is that partial view is added into the middle of the table and the browser is struggling to render the table correctly.

if you add a `<td></td>` tag around the partial view then the table will render correctly.

```js
    function viewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.myProperty = ko.observable(new Foo());

    }

    function Foo() {
      var self = this;
      self.myListB = ko.observableArray([new Model1(), new Model1()]);
      self.myPropertyA = '';
    }

    function Model1() {
      var self = this;
      self.Property1 = "test 1";
      self.Property2 = "test 2";
    }

    var vm = new viewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!--ko with: myProperty-->
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: myListB-->
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Property1"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Property2"></td>
      <td>
        <div class="modal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content ">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">MyTitle</h4>
              </div>
              <!--ko if: $data!=null -->
              <div class="modal-body ">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Property1"></span>
              </div>
              <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)" />
```